# Why has my CDROM drive has disappeared from My Computer?

Tags: windows-xp, optical-drive, compact-disc

I have an HP DC7900 with Windows XP SP3 installed on it. I also have a Digital Recorder DS4000 but it's the only USB device shown in my computer. The CD drive has gone...

Has anybody seen this issue before?

I also tried the Microsoft fix at the [following address](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982116/en-us) without any success

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I was going to suggest the fix-it. :( Are you sure the drive hasn't come unplugged internally?  Does it work on another machine?  Did you just install iTunes?

Comment: Is it visible under device manager?

Comment: @Sathya: It's not visible in Device Manager but it is in the BIOS. I don't get it... And yes, iTunes has been installed quite a back ago but updated recently.

Comment: Do a quick check under your System Errors http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310414 , do you see anything unusual? Maybe disk errors, for example?

Comment: Sathya has a good point. It is possible that there was a hardware failure and Windows can no longer 'see' the device.

Comment: Sathya, can you please post this as an answer. There was a HW failure. I had to change the SATA DVD Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few years back and this link saved me.

http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f149/solved-missing-dvd-cd-drive-202706.html

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)